# Parallel transport on a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $N$ an embedded submanifold of $M$. Now I have a geodesic $c \colon (-a,a) \to N$ with $a>0$ and $c(0)=p$ in $N$, s.t. $c'(0)$ is orthogonal to $T_pN$.

Is the parallel transport of $c'(0)$ along $c$ still orthogonal to $T_qN$?

Parallel transport is an isometry, so I think the question is equivalent to whether or not the tangent space of $N$ at $c(0)$ is mapped to the tangent space at $c(t)$ by the parallel transport. Unfortunately I haven't an answer to this.

Regards.

Comment: Since $c$ maps to $N$, you have $c'(0) \in T_p N$, so $c'(0) = 0$ by orthogonality. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Replace the curve by $c:(-a,a)\rightarrow M$.

Comment: This question really doesn't make sense. If $c$ is a geodesic that starts out *orthogonal* to $N$, it will not locally encounter $N$ again. Do you mean for $c$ to be a geodesic *in* $N$ and to consider parallel transport of a vector that starts out orthogonal to $N$?